# Is conversation ID the same to everyone in outlook javascript API?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I want to create an Add-in for Outlook for my office using [Yeoman Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) that just shows a simple side-pane where when you select a **conversation** you can add your notes, then these notes are shown to everyone (within this add-in indeed) and they can be edited. Now I've explored microsoft docs and the only thing I found is that the conversationID changes when you change the subject, but beside this problem there is no reference about this being unique for everyone that received that particular e-mail, does anyone has any clue about it?
Thank you very much in advance to you all!

Comment: Can you clarify, which API are you calling to get the conversation Id?

Comment: Javascript API it's written in the title, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: Are you using this JS API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#conversationId. This conversationId is not shared among for everyone who is on the conversation. The conversationId will be different for each recipient.

Comment: Yeah too bad, thank you for the response, so basically my idea is not possibile, I cannot create "shared notes" on the same conversation for everyone right? The idea was to store notes in a common network and that my add-in was picking these notes and link them to conversation by some identifiers but there are no common identifiers in Outlook. Let me know if I am right. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: That is correct. Currently this feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins